# Multiple select statement in single mySQL query with group by clause common to all

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to get this output. that is group by date wise with count of error codes of each day with it.

```
 Todays_Date  | 521_ERROR | 527_ERROR |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2017-09-14  |     26098 |     35870 |
| 2017-09-15  |     26098 |     35870 |
| 2017-09-16  |     26098 |     35870 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

But with this query I am only getting Date grouped as 14, 15, 16 but count of error codes are getting as whole count from 14 Sept to 20 Sept and printing same data next to each date.

I want date as group 14 with count of errorcodes for 14 next to date 14 then 15 and count of errorcodes of 15 next to 15 like that

Please help with this.

```
select * FROM  
(select DATE(DATE_Record) AS Todays_Date from Sale_1 where (DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-20 23:59:59') group by DAY(DATE_Record)) as DATE_1,
(select count(RESPONSECODE) AS 521_ERROR from Sale_1 where ERRORCODE='521' AND (DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-14 23:59:59')) as 521_ERROR,
(select count(RESPONSECODE) AS 527_ERROR from Sale_1 where ERRORCODE='527' and (DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-14 23:59:59')) as 527_ERROR;
```

Comment: Provide sample data set to product this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by below query.

```
select DATE(DATE_Record) AS "Todays_Date", sum(if(ERRORCODE=521,1,0)) as 521_ERROR, sum(if(ERRORCODE=527,1,0)) as 527_ERROR
FROM  Sale_1 
where (DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-20 23:59:59') 
group by date(DATE_Record))
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for these complex correlated sub queries. Make it simple using `CASE` expression with `GROUP BY` date like this:

```
SELECT
 DATE(Date_Record),
 SUM(CASE WHEN ERRORCODE = '521' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS 521_ERROR,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ERRORCODE = '527' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS 527_ERROR
FROM Table
WHERE DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-20 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(Date_Record);
```

Or you can make it shorter as suggested by **@MKhalidJunaid**:

```
SELECT
 DATE(Date_Record),
 SUM(ERRORCODE = '521') AS 521_ERROR,
 SUM(ERRORCODE = '521') AS 527_ERROR
FROM Table
WHERE DATE_Record BETWEEN '2017-09-14 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-20 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(Date_Record);
```

Comment: Even shorter `SUM(ERRORCODE = '521' )` for mysql only

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - Thanks, didn't know that